# How do I access the html object I add the event listener to instead of the item being clicked in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event listener for an object and when I click the object it's fine, but when I click the child, event.target returns the child. Is there a way to make it so that it only returns the object I assigned the event listener to?

This is what I have as of now:

```
function myFunction(event) {
    if (event.target == something) {
        console.log('test') // expected test every time I click the object something in the html
    }
}

something.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
somethingelse.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```

It only logs 'test' in the console when I click the margin/padding outside of the child because technically the event.target is not 'something' and rather the child of something.

Is there any way to access the object I am adding the event listener to (something) rather than the item being clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **currentTarget** property instead of **target** property. The **target** property returns the element that triggered the event, while **currentTarget** returns the element to which the event listener is attached.

```
function myFunction(event) {
if (event.currentTarget == something) {
    console.log('test')
}
}
something.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
somethingelse.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```

**event.currentTarget** will always be the element to which the event listener is attached (something in this case), regardless of which child element was actually clicked.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget :

> The `currentTarget` read-only property of the `Event` interface identifies **the element to which the event handler has been attached**.

> This will not always be the same as the element on which the event was *fired*, because the event may have fired on a *descendant of the element with the handler*, and then ***bubbled up*** to the element with the handler. The element on which the event was fired is given by `Event.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of what you can do to achieve this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="something">Something
      <div id="somethingelse">Something Else</div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      function myFunction(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("target: ", event.target.id, "currentTarget:", event.currentTarget.id);

        if (event.currentTarget.id == 'something') {
          console.log("test"); // expected test every time I click the object something in the html
        }
      }

      document
        .getElementById("something")
        .addEventListener("click", myFunction,true);
      document
        .getElementById("somethingelse")
        .addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use **event.currentTarget** to get the element where the eventListener is attached to.

You'll notice the code sample has 2 additional points :

1. `addEventListener('click', myFunction, true);`
2. `event.stopPropagation()`

Explanation here:

**Event handling:**

There're two types of event handling to determine order of processing in javascript whenever something is clicked on:

- "bubbling" - as it's name implies, events bubble from child to parent. This is the default mode when you use `addEventListener` without specifying the 3rd parameter ([useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#usecapture)).
- "capturing" - the inverse of "bubbling", events travel from parent to child. To use capturing mode, set like so in the `addEventListener` function,  `addEventListener('click', myFunction, true)`;

Based on your example code above, there are 2 event listeners, one on the parent, one on the child. Clicking the child will run the function twice. Depending on what you need, you can use event.stopPropagation() to prevent the event from "bubbling upwards", or "going further down" the DOM tree.

You can remove `event.stopPropgation` to see the event being trigger at both parent, and child. Check this link for more information about [Bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)